# adldap2-laravel can see AD user but will not import them

Tags: php, import, laravel-5.4

So I configured Adldap2-Laravel to the best of my ability thus far. It won't login for me just yet and says invalid credentials when I try. So I ran the console command to try an import my users (just to see what happens). It says it finds all of my users (663) and when I tell it to import them it looks like it is... progress bar etc runs, but then it says 0 imported and my DB has nothing...

I have followed the docs online as best I can. I modified the users migration and refreshed it, taking out email and putting in 'username' and replacing 'email' with 'username' throughout the code. I also replaced 'email' on the login.blade.php file as well. As I said, I can't get it to login and as you can see above it does not want to import any users either.

Any troubleshooting tips or help would be appreciated!

***UPDATE***

I have it importing fine. It was a DB configuration issue. Lesson learned - check the Laravel logs. That being said, once the first login occurs for a user, it stores it into the DB. Authentication that first time works properly. After the user is in the DB however authentication breaks. As long as you provide it with a valid username it will accept ANY password...

Comment: If you got the solution, why don't you answer the question by yourself? It might help other people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple... I had forgot to check my log files. In there I saw that it was trying to make the import but I had added a field called "role" for the user roles and it did not have a default value and it was complaining about that. After I gave it a default value for the field  in my migrations file it started importing fine... now onto the next step of it not wanting to authenticate on login!